# Allow site access only with domain url (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have configured an instance on AWS, and am able to access my site with both of the following URLs: http://example.com and http://ec2-12-34-56-789.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

How can I disable access to the second URL and only keep only http://example.com?

Comment: Is this a VPC or EC2-Classic instance?

Comment: @RodrigoM This is VPC, but I would be glad to know solution for EC2-Classic also. Have spent a hours yesterday searching for any information, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an instance is launched into a VPC, AWS provides the instance with public and private DNS hostnames if DNS hostnames are enabled for the VPC.

By default, this feature is only enabled for default VPCs and VPCs that you create using the VPC wizard in the VPC console.

Your VPC setting has this feature enabled.  In order to disable it, please follow the following steps:

- Login to the AWS console
- Click on **Services**
- Click on **VPC**
- Click on **Your VPCs**
- Select the VPC you are using
- Click on the **Action** button
- From the pull-down menu, select **Edit DNS hostnames**
- In the **Edit DNS hostnames** dialog, select **Yes**

You may need to relaunch your instance in that VPC to remove the existing public DNS Name.

For more information see [Updating DNS Support for Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating)

Comment: Did you mean NO on last step?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, 
There was Yes in my setup.
I have changed as you said (Edit DNS hostnames -> No), then reboot instance, and public DNS now blank in description tab, but I am still able to access my site in browser with this public DNS. I thought that I need to wait until DNS cache updates, but after two days public hostname is still accessible.

Comment: I do not get name resolution here in the US on http://ec2-12-34-56-789.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/.  The EC2 public DNS name are based on IP# so as long as you have that IP, that name may still resolve.  Try to assign it a new IP by relaunching, or assigning a new Elastic IP number,